# Duplicity Errno 28 No space left on device

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

In addition to problems restoring files from Deja-Dup copies without Nautilus, duplicity can't even say on which device it lacks space while trying to restore a big backup.

Comment: Richard, Eric, Florian, Radu and Braiam. This Q&A is for people like me that are searching for a solution of a problem. Bug report would be about another, better way of solving this problem by improving `duplicity` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with `/tmp` being in 1G `tmpfs`.

```
sudo mount -o bind /media/username/bigdisk/tmp /tmp
```

solved the problem.

Please write a bug report against `duplicity` about it.